Using Pandas to get year over year change from Excel file
I have an excel file that looks something like this: 
Each row represents a month of the year, each column is a user_ID, and the cell is the dollars that user spent in a month.
The file gets updated a few times a month, and I don't always get the data for the previous month (e.g. June 2024) until sometimes until a month later like the end of July.
What would be the best way using Pandas to calculate the year-over-year change in spending in aggregate for all of the users? Users without any spend in the prior year period (e.g. May 2023) should be excluded as well as if they don't have data in the current period (e.g. May 2024). In this example, I would like to calculate the year-over-year change for the 2nd quarter, so that would mean only users 2, 3, 5 would be included, but also for May 2024, which would mean users 2, 3, 4, 5.
Would using psycopg2 be easier to just add this into a PSQL DB?
This is what I've tried so far:
import datetime
import pandas as pd
# import psycopg2

def open_file(path):

    df = pd.read_excel(path, skiprows=53,
                       nrows=140, usecols="M:CCL")
    users = df.columns[1:-1]
    cur_month_vals = []
    prev_month_vals = []
    cur_month = '2024-05-01'
    prev_month = '2023-05-01'

    for user in df[1:-1]:
        try:
            if cur_month in df.columns and prev_month in df.columns:
                cur_spend = df.loc[cur_month, user]
                print(user, cur_month, cur_spend)
                prev_spend = df.loc[pre_month, user]
                print(cur_spend/prev_spend)

        except:
            print("user not in", user)

Edit: using the raw data, I now have something that looks like this


The screenshot looks like a Excel pivot table. I suspect it would be easier to get the DataFrame from the unpivot Excel data and then use something like DataFrame.groupby.

Yes, the data is from a pivot table. The raw data gives individual transactions for each user by month, so there can be multiple transactions per month for a user, and the pivot table just sums up the values.

@AxelRichter Just curious why you think it might be easier to do from the raw data versus the pivot table?

This is a Pandas question, not a psycopg2 one, removing the psycopg2 tag.

You could try pd.shift:
import pandas as pd
data = {1: [None, None, 1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
       2: [None, 5, 1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
       3: [None, 1, 1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,None,None,None],
       'date': [f'{y}-{m:02}' for y in [2023,2024] for m in range(1,13)][0:16]
       }


df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('date')
(df - df.shift(12)).sum(axis=1)

Input:
            1     2     3
date                     
2023-01   NaN   NaN   NaN
2023-02   NaN   5.0   1.0
2023-03   1.0   1.0   1.0
2023-04   2.0   2.0   2.0
2023-05   3.0   3.0   3.0
2023-06   4.0   4.0   4.0
2023-07   5.0   5.0   5.0
2023-08   6.0   6.0   6.0
2023-09   7.0   7.0   7.0
2023-10   8.0   8.0   8.0
2023-11   9.0   9.0   9.0
2023-12  10.0  10.0  10.0
2024-01  11.0  11.0  11.0
2024-02  12.0  12.0   NaN
2024-03  13.0  13.0   NaN
2024-04  14.0  14.0   NaN

Results:
date
2023-01     0.0
2023-02     0.0
2023-03     0.0
2023-04     0.0
2023-05     0.0
2023-06     0.0
2023-07     0.0
2023-08     0.0
2023-09     0.0
2023-10     0.0
2023-11     0.0
2023-12     0.0
2024-01     0.0
2024-02     7.0
2024-03    24.0
2024-04    24.0
dtype: float64

